# how to determine which button has been clicked in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm using a php loop to generate multiple button elements. How can I determine which button has been clicked by using jquery?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

    if(button.click){
        alert(button.id);
    }

});

</script>

<?php for($x=0; $x<4; $x++){ ?>
<ul id="x">
<li><input type="button" id="<?php echo $x; ?>" value="<?php echo $x; ?>"/></li>
</ul>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: You aren't actually putting the ID attribute onto the input.

Comment: Any of the answers below should now solve your problem, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common way to identify a element is id. `(Literally, id does mean "identification")`

The way you want it, should be something like this.

```
$("input").click(function() { //This will attach the function to all the input elements
   alert($(this).attr('id')); //This will grab the id of the element and alert. Although $(this).id also work, I like this way.
});
```

However, generalizing the bind to all the input elements might be a bad idea. So try giving a common class to specific elements and use `$(".yourclass")` instead.

Answer (score 3):

well, if your code looks like the below

```
$('input:button').click(function(){
   $(this); //this will always refer to the clicked button. 
            //You can use traversal to find stuff relative to this button
   var butId = $(this).attr('id'); //this will give you the ID of the clicked button
});
```

Comment: +1 for good explanation, here is [test case](http://jsfiddle.net/PAG3y/) for anyone who want. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php for($x=0; $x<4; $x++){ ?>
<ul id="x">
<li><input type="button" id="<?php echo $x; ?>"  value="<?php echo $x; ?>"/></li>
</ul>
<?php } ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("input").click(function() {
        clickButton(this) // this is the button element, same as alert(this.id)
    });

    function clickButton(button) {
        alert(button.id)
    }
</script>
```

EDIT: binding per JS is preferred

Comment: Using onclick isn't recommended. Best to bind via JS

Comment: better, but you don't need `clickButton` anymore. Sorry if I sound like I'm nitpicking :)

Comment: well, when binding with the "onclick" I didn't **need** the function either, could have written `onclick="alert('this.id')"`.

Comment: no no, what I meant was you've already defined a function to handle the click event (your anonymous function). You can simply move the `alert` inside your click method.

Comment: jup, I'm aware of that, but by using a named function `clickButton` I can call that function from elsewhere in my code. Of course this makes more sense when more login is involved.

Comment: I'm +1 you now because I've given you so much grief :)  As to your last comment, you can do this `$("input").click(clickbutton);`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $("input[type='button']").click(function(event) {
        //event.target is the html causing the event
    });
});
```